# Date and time validation

Tags: list, date-time, validation, settings

In my SharePoint 2013 I have 4 columns **Start Date** (date only), **Start Time** (Single line of text, max 5 characters), **End Date** (date only) and **End Time** (Single line of text, max 5 characters).

I want to come up with a List validation formula that will say:
If End Date is equal to Start Date then End Time must be greater than Start Time and if End Date is greater than Start Date then End time can be any time.

I have the same rule in nintex form now I want to apply it in a List so when the users decide to use datasheet view the same rule will apply.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use date time column. It will be much easier than this. You can refer to following link. SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 will be similar for column validation.

[refer this link](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/how-to-validate-a-due-date-in-a-sharepoint-2010-list/)

Comment: That was my first option but seconds increments in 5s, in date and time control that is why I ended up date and time column for Date and a single of text for Time.

Comment: You can not refer to another column in the same list with validation formula. What about InfoPath forms? I guess you can do this using InfoPath form and rules.